# Explanation of the Shell Method

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: help]

Could someone explain all of the steps, as well as where the values came from? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks like a straightforward application of the shell method. What step in particular are you having trouble with?

Comment: How to get r and h and why we use those values

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the shell method, you want to take a line segment in the region being revolved which is parallel to the axis you're revolving around.  In this case, that means you are using horizontal line segments, so you are integrating with respect to y.

Then $\displaystyle V=\int_0^{m^2}2\pi r(y)h(y) dy$ since the graphs intersect at the point $(m,m^2)$, and

r is the distance from the line segment to the axis of revolution, so in this case $r=y$, while

h is the length of the line segment, which is given by the difference of the x-coordinates; so $\displaystyle h=\sqrt{y}-\frac{y}{m}$.